# How to access Firestore increment method from a v2 Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

In Firebase Cloud Functions v1, to increment a Firestore field, one would import admin and access it from `FieldValue`.

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
```

However, in v2, this is no longer the case. And attempting to do this through the `firestore` instance does not work.

```
const {getFirestore} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

getFirestore().FieldValue.increment(1) // this does not work
```

What is the proper way to access the increment method in v2?

Answer (score 1):

In the modular API, [`increment`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#increment) is a global, top-level function.

So import it with:

```
const {getFirestore, increment} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");
```

And then use the function where needed, without any namespace:

```
increment(1)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. However, if I change it to `const {getFirestore, FieldValue} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");` and then access it with `FieldValue.increment(1)`, then it works.

Comment: Ah, that looks like the normal documented variant for Node.js then: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#node.js_13 

Answer (score 0):

As [@puf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) said, the change is to the way that the Admin SDK has evolved in terms of its API exports for its many services including Firestore.  This is not an issue of Cloud Functions Gen 1 vs Gen 2.  The changes to the Admin SDK and  Client SDK in terms of "modular API" have happened roughly in the same timeline that Gen 2 got introduced to Cloud Functions.